# Reshaping array of objects in required format using lodash.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

How to format data based on columns?
Here i needs to convert one row to 2 rows based on category1 and category2 fileds.

**Input Data Format:**

```html
[
  {
    'Name' : 'Project A',
    'category1' : 20,
    'category2 : 10
   }
]
```

**Output Data Format:**

```html
        [
          {
            'Name' : 'Project A',
            'category' : 'category1',
            'value' : 20
           },
           {
            'Name' : 'Project A',
            'category' : 'category2',
            'value' : 10
           }
        ]
```

Comment: Shouldn't the output for the first object have a value of 20?

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @Kobe first object value is 20. it's my mistake. corrected now.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've made a basic attempt, so I'm just going to give you an outline of what to do. What you want to do is, step1: create a new array to hold your results, step2: iterate over each member of your first array, step3: over each member, check the 'category1' value and add an appropriate object to the results array, step4: also check the category2 value for each member and add an appropriate object to the results array, step5: return the results array.

Answer (score 2):

Your input is quite vague, but I have built a solution that will work for multiple objects, and if those object's have more categories than others, assuming the key contains `category`:

```js
const arr = [{
  'Name': 'Project A',
  'category1': 20,
  'category2': 10
}]

const unpack = arr => arr.flatMap(o =>
  Object.entries(o).filter(([key]) => key.includes('category'))
    .map(([category, value]) => ({ Name: o.Name, category, value }))
)

console.log(unpack([{ 'Name': 'Project A', 'category1': 20, 'category2': 10 }]))
console.log(unpack([{ 'Name': 'Project A', 'category1': 20, 'category2': 10, 'category3': 5 }]))
console.log(unpack([
  { 'Name': 'Project A', 'category1': 20, 'category2': 10, 'category3': 5 },
  { 'Name': 'Project B', 'category1': 20, 'category2': 10 }
]))
```

Answer (score 1):

genius! @Kobe. As for more general cases, I use

```js
const inputArr = [
  {idVar1: "a", idVar2: "b", category1: 1, category2: 2},
  {idVar1: "a", idVar2: "c", category1: 3, category2: 4},
] 

const unpack = (arr, idVars, keyName, valName) =>
  arr.flatMap(o => {
    const idObj = Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(o).filter(([key]) => idVars.indexOf(key) !== -1)
    );

    return Object.entries(o)
      .filter(([key]) => idVars.indexOf(key) === -1)
      .map(([key, value]) => ({ ...idObj, [keyName]: key, [valName]: value}));
  });

console.log(unpack(inputArr, ["idVar1", "idVar2"], "x", "y"))

// [
//   { idVar1: 'a', idVar2: 'b', x: 'category1', y: 1 },
//   { idVar1: 'a', idVar2: 'b', x: 'category2', y: 2 },
//   { idVar1: 'a', idVar2: 'c', x: 'category1', y: 3 },
//   { idVar1: 'a', idVar2: 'c', x: 'category2', y: 4 }
// ]
```